# Implement QSB like suggestions in android app

Tags: android, search, search-suggestion, android-qsb

I need to give a search box in my android app. As the user starts typing in the search text, I need to show him relevant suggestions. (As we see in the google-search widget on the home screen. If we see from the logs, `com.android.quicksearchbox/.SearchActivity` is started with `android.search.action.GLOBAL_SEARCH` intent and it searches in following:  `corpora:[web, apps, com.android.contacts/.activities.PeopleActivity])`.

Only thing is I need the suggestions to be displayed from the web & my application DB.

Any idea how to implement this ? Do I need to implement my own `SuggestionsProvider` or can I directly use the native implementation? If so, how?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/adding-custom-suggestions.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think i figure it out myself.

Went through [Searchable Dictionary](http://jayxie.com/mirrors/android-sdk/resources/samples/SearchableDictionary/index.html) code & QuickSearchBox code in android source.

Need two start 2 activities in a background thread. One will search for the search-term in my DB & other will search the same in Google. All the results will be seen in the suggestion list.

[Google Suggest API](http://google.com/complete/search?q=res&output=toolbar)  provides suggestions as the user enters the text.

Comment: Hey, could you elaborate a little? like, how do you start Google search activity in a background thread? or how do you get its search results?